# Tornado to push multiple responses for one request

Tags: python, python-2.7, websocket, tornado

Im in requirement to push multiple responses for every request from the client side. Im making use of tornado for this purpose with websockets.

I am relatively new to tornado and from what i understand.

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import socket

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
      print 'new connection'

    def on_message(self, message):
      print 'message received:  %s' % message
      # Reverse Message and send it back
      print 'sending back message: %s' % message[::-1]
      self.write_message('%s:%s' % (i,message[::-1]))

    def on_close(self):
      print 'connection closed'

    def check_origin(self, origin):
      return True

application = tornado.web.Application([
  (r'/ws', WSHandler),
])
```

how do i make the on_message function push multiple requests.

The html code i use,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WebSockets Hello World</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        text-align: center;
        min-width: 500px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      // log function
      log = function(data){
        $("div#terminal").prepend("</br>" +data);
        console.log(data);
      };

      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div#message_details").hide()

        var ws;

        $("#open").click(function(evt) {
          evt.preventDefault();

          var host = $("#host").val();
          var port = $("#port").val();
          var uri = $("#uri").val();

          // create websocket instance
          ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + host + ":" + port + uri);

          // Handle incoming websocket message callback
          ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
            log("Message Received: " + evt.data)
            alert("message received: " + evt.data);
            };

          // Close Websocket callback
          ws.onclose = function(evt) {
            log("***Connection Closed***");
            alert("Connection close");
            $("#host").css("background", "#ff0000"); 
            $("#port").css("background", "#ff0000"); 
            $("#uri").css("background",  "#ff0000");
            $("div#message_details").empty();

            };

          // Open Websocket callback
          ws.onopen = function(evt) { 
            $("#host").css("background", "#00ff00"); 
            $("#port").css("background", "#00ff00"); 
            $("#uri").css("background", "#00ff00");
            $("div#message_details").show();
            log("***Connection Opened***");
          };
        });

        // Send websocket message function
        $("#send").click(function(evt) {
            log("Sending Message: "+$("#message").val());
            ws.send($("#message").val());
        });

      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>WebSockets Hello World</h1>
    <div id="connection_details">
      <label for="host">host:</label>
      <input type="text" id="host" value="localhost" style="background:#ff0000;"/><br />
      <label for="port">port:</label>
      <input type="text" id="port" value="8888" style="background:#ff0000;"/><br />
      <label for="uri">uri:</label>
      <input type="text" id="uri" value="/ws" style="background:#ff0000;"/><br />
      <input type="submit" id="open" value="open" />
    </div>
    <div id="message_details">
        </br></br>
        <label for="message">message:</label>
        <input type="text" id="message" value="Hello World!"/><br />
        <input type="submit" id="send" value="send" />
    </div>
    <div id="terminal">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `write_message` multiple times.

e.g.

```
def on_message(self, message):
    self.write_message("Message one")
    self.write_message("Message two")
```

Comment: Can you post that code and error? The above works for me

Comment: i have added the html code i use..i dont get any error, i just get one alert box of the first send_message.

Comment: It works for me. Can you post your exact server code too

Comment: work fine too, dono why it initially failed but works fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On your code you open a single WebSocket and then you request multiple responses to this opened WebSocket. To achieve multiple responses you can follow Henry Heath suggestions calling `write_message` multiple times.

However in cases where you want to achieve multiple responses for multiple  WebSockets you can follow the approach below.

```
clients = [] # list of opened WebSocket clients
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        clients.append(self) # append a newly opened WebSocket client
        print 'new connection'

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received:  %s' % message
        # loop over the opened WebSocket clients and send a message
        for client in clients:
            # Reverse Message and send it back
            print 'sending back message: %s' % message[::-1]
            client.write_message('%s' % (message[::-1]))

    def on_close(self):
        clients.remove(self) # remove a newly closed WebSocket client
        print 'connection closed'

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True
```

On your template(index.html) you just need to click the button *Open* a couple of times to open a couple of new WebSocktes and then by clicking the button *Send* you will see that you will get multiple responds , as many as the number of the WebSockets you opened.

This is handy for applications in which you need to broadcat a message to multiple clients, such as live chats.

Also make sure to check the [official excellent Tornado documentation for WebSockets](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html).

Comment: I disagree - you can send multiple messages to a single connection. Opening a new websocket connection for each message is unnecessary and defeats the point having a connection in the first place

Comment: Yes you are right. Your suggestion works - I have edited my respond.